# Passing a member function with arguments in pthreads in C++

Tags: c++, pthreads

I am passing a class member function to pthread_create and getting below error. I know there are so many queries already on stackoverflow and they are saying that make a static helper around class member function and pass that static function in the pthread and function callback as last argument in the pthread_create but in my case, the member functions has arguments also. So, my problem is slightly different one. **Where should I pass the member function arguments ?** Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct Point
{
  int y;
  int z;
};

class A
{
  int x;

  public:
    int getX();
    void setX(int val) {x = val;}

    void* func(void* args) 
    {
      Point p = *(Point *)args;

      int y = p.y;
      int z = p.z;

      return (void *)(x + y + z); 
    }


    void myFunc()
    {
      int y = 12;
      int z = 2;

      pthread_t tid;

      Point p;
      p.y = y;
      p.z = z;

      pthread_create(&tid, NULL, func, &p);
      pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  A a;

  a.myFunc();

  return 0;
}
```

**Error :**

```
 classThreads.c: In member function ‘void A::myFunc()’:
classThreads.c:40:42: error: cannot convert ‘A::func’ from type ‘void* (A::)(void*)’ to type ‘void* (*)(void*)’
       pthread_create(&tid, NULL, func, &p);
```

Comment: The problem is not with the arguments but the `this` pointer for the member function.

Comment: I know @JustinFinnerty and I also know the solution but the solution is for those member functions who does not have any arguments, i want a solution for those member functions, who has arguments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cannot convert '\*void(MyClass::\*)(void\*) to void\*(\*)(void\*) in pthread\_create function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12006097/cannot-convert-voidmyclassvoid-to-voidvoid-in-pthread-create-fu)

Comment: Not duplicate as question specifically asks how to do this with member function that takes arguments.

Comment: Why not use `std::thread`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not passing a `this` pointer to the thread create method. This needs to be added to the argument list.

```
#include <utility>
#include <pthread.h>

struct Point
{
  int y;
  int z;
};

class A
{
  int x;

  public:
    int getX();
    void setX(int val) {x = val;}

    static void* func(void* args) 
    {
      std::pair< A*, Point > tp = *(std::pair< A*, Point > *)args;

      int y = tp.second.y;
      int z = tp.second.z;

      return (void *)(tp.first->x + y + z); 
    }


    void myFunc()
    {
      int y = 12;
      int z = 2;

      pthread_t tid;

      Point p;
      p.y = y;
      p.z = z;
      std::pair< A*, Point > tp( this, p );
      pthread_create(&tid, NULL, func, &tp);
      pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  A a;

  a.myFunc();

  return 0;
}
```

You can use the `std::tuple` class to pass the `this` pointer and more than one argument.